# jQuery go to a div on my page

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have url that ends like this /#mydiv

in my page I have div like so `<div id="mydiv"></div>`

I am looking to write a script that will bring me to that div when the page loads.

I tried

```
window.location.hash = window.location.hash
```

but it does not work in IE

Answer (score 0):

This should work, first create an anchor link inside the div, or also ".before" should work instead of ".prepend"

```
$('div#mydiv').prepend('<a name="mydiv">&nbsp;</a>');
```

Better would be, having the anchor in the html output.